# Search Configuration Import CSOM

Tags: search, client-object-model, search-configuration

I'm trying to import a search configuration XML using a SharePoint App.

I have check the following:

- The XML is correct. I can upload it manually.
- The code works using a console app, but not using the SharePoint app.

Following code:

```
    SearchConfigurationPortability searchConfig = new SearchConfigurationPortability(this.Context);
    SearchObjectOwner owner = new SearchObjectOwner(this.Context, SearchObjectLevel.SPWeb);
    searchConfig.ImportSearchConfiguration(owner, configurationLocation);
    this.Context.Load(searchConfig);
    this.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Following error message:

```
ServerException was caught
The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults
(either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the <serviceDebug> configuration behavior)
on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server
trace logs.
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, and it seems the event handler does not work properly when triggered by an App. I'm thinking of doing a workaround using the UI to get this triggered for an App I'm testing, where I will open a page on the host web and use JSOM to do the schema import. A bit hackish, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason you are trying to import the Search Config via code?

You can directly add the Search Config as a Visual Studio Project Item and it should get deployed through your App:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2013/05/30/add-search-capabilities-to-your-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link @vardhaman. However, I found on [link](http://community.office365.com/en-us/b/office_365_community_blog/archive/2013/05/31/importing-search-configurations-with-sharepoint-apps-grid-user-post.aspx) that "managed properties aren’t supported in this deployment model" and I was hoping to work around it this way. The goal of the app is to configure the site collection incl. the complete search configuration.

Comment: Furthermore, I used the code found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn205276(v=office.15).aspx) that I thought should work?

Comment: I exported the search schema including managed properties with PowerShell. [Here](http://davistrent.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-search-exporting-and-importing-search-configuration-settings) is shown how.